# Agenda.js job scheduling, jobs repeat and loop

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging, job-scheduling

Thanks in advance for anyone who reads this.

I need to be able to send gcm messages (notifications) to a list of client IDs at a certain time.

I am trying to use Agenda.js since it has a persistence layer.

The following code seems to work just fine initially, executing exactly when it is supposed to. But, after a while of letting the server just chill doing nothing, the job will start executing in a loop.

It will also include

"WARNING: Date in past. Will never be fired."

Here is the relevant code.

```
var agenda = new agenda({db: {address: configParams.db}});

schedule_notifications = function(req) {

// define an agenda task named notify
    agenda.define('notify', function(job, done) {

     // create a gcm message
        var message = new gcm.Message({
            notification: { "body": 'test' }
        });
        var sender = new gcm.Sender('server id');
        var regTokens = ['phone id'];

        // send the message
        sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            else console.log(response);
            done();
        });
    });


    // get the object from the request
    var req_json = JSON.parse(req.body.data),
        keys = Object.keys(req_json),
        key_string = keys[0],
        start_obj = new Date(req_json[key_string][0].start);

    // schedule the job with the date object found in the request
    // start_obj, for example could be made using
    // start_obj = new Date();
    // notify is the name of the job to run

    agenda.schedule(start_obj, 'notify');
    agenda.start();

// can comment agenda.schedule and uncomment the following line to delete the unfinished jobs in db
// agenda.purge(function(err, numRemoved) {});    
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this could be happening? Any tips on how to debug this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem. I added in the job.remove function and it no longer spazzes.

```
var agenda = new agenda({db: {address: configParams.db}});

schedule_notifications = function(req) {

// define an agenda task named notify
    agenda.define('notify', function(job, done) {

     // create a gcm message
        var message = new gcm.Message({
            notification: { "body": 'test' }
        });
        var sender = new gcm.Sender('server id');
        var regTokens = ['phone id'];

        // send the message
        sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            else console.log(response);
            done();
        });
    job.remove(function(err) {
      if(!err) console.log("Successfully removed job from collection");
    })
    });


    // get the object from the request
    var req_json = JSON.parse(req.body.data),
        keys = Object.keys(req_json),
        key_string = keys[0],
        start_obj = new Date(req_json[key_string][0].start);

    // schedule the job with the date object found in the request
    // start_obj, for example could be made using
    // start_obj = new Date();
    // notify is the name of the job to run

    agenda.schedule(start_obj, 'notify');
    agenda.start();

// can comment agenda.schedule and uncomment the following line to delete the unfinished jobs in db
// agenda.purge(function(err, numRemoved) {});    
}
```